# Tensorflow Object API TF2 not displaying visualizations in Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow

Description

I had a setup for training using the object detection API that worked really well, however I have had to upgrade from TF1.15 to TF2 and so instead of using model_main.py I am now using model_main_tf2.py  and using mobilenet ssd 320x320 pipeline to transfer train a new model.

When training my model in TF1.15 it would display a whole heap of scalars as well as detection box image samples. It was fantastic.

In TF2 training I get no such data, just loss scalars and 3 input images!! and yet the event files are huge gigabytes! where as they were in hundreds of megs using TF1.15

The thing is there is nowhere to specify what data is presented. I have not changed anything other than which model_main py file I use to run the training. I added num_visualizations: to the pipeline config file but no visualizations of detection boxes appear.

Can someone please explain to me what is going on? I need to be able to see whats happening throughout training!

Thank You

I am training on PC in virtual environment before performing TRT optimization in Linux but I think that is irrelevant here really.

Environment
**GPU Type**: P220
**Operating System + Version**: Win10 Pro
**Python Version (if applicable)**:  3.6
**TensorFlow Version (if applicable)**:  2

Relevant Files

TF1.15 vs TF2 screenshots:
[TF1 (model_main.py) Tensorboard Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlDMB.jpg)
[TF2 (model_main_tf2.py) Tensorboard Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9Wj9.jpg)

Steps To Reproduce

The repo I am working with [GitHub Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)

[Model](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz)
[Pipeline Config File](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/configs/tf2/ssd_mobilenet_v2_320x320_coco17_tpu-8.config)

UPDATE: I have investigated further and discovered that the tensorboard settings are being set in [Object Detection Trainer 1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_lib.py) for TF1.15 and [Object Detection Trainer 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py) for TF2

So if someone who knows more than I do about this could work out what the difference is and what I need to do to get same result in tensorboard with v2 as I do with the first one that would be amazing and save me enormous headache. It would seem that this, even though it is documented as being for TF2, is not actually following TF2 syntax but I could be wrong.